# "ImportError: No module named Tkinter" even though I've used Tkinter programs as recent as yesterday and no substantial changes were made?

Tags: python, debugging, import, tkinter, importerror

I'm getting a Tkinter error even though it was imported and used yesterday. I have a Windows 7 OS and am running Python 2, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do at this point. My google-fu is weak today, I can't seem to bring up anything relevant. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the results of `import sys; print sys.path`

Comment: Did you create a file named `Tkinter.py` perhaps? Doing so in your current working directory might mask the standard module of the same name...

Comment: @unutbu: That would lead to `AttributeError`, not `ImportError`.

Comment: @delnan: Oops, right. I read the body of the question, and ignored the title...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, unutbu and delnan: I realized I have two versions of Python2 and Python3 installed. When something is run without opening its corresponding IDLE first, it opens it it the later edition: Python 3, when the program I wrote was in Python 2. That led to the error. Thanks anyways guys!

Comment: @Louis93: if you have figured out the solution to your problem on your own, you should post the fix as an answer.

Comment: Though in a case like that, you could always wrap it in a `try` and do `except ImportError: import tkinter`. It wouldn't resolve the other potential problems with running Python 2 code with a Python 3 interpreter, but it would avoid the `Tkinter` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you most likely have more than one Python installed on your system and you're running the program from a version different from the one you programmed it in.

By default, a Python program on your PC will usually be opened in the latest edition of Python.

Comment: This can happen on any OS, it's not specific to Windows.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, just fixed my post.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check if the version of the Python interpreter used to run the script got changed somehow.

`import tkinter` works in python 3 (instead of Tkinter).